# Why Yammer Post Message Error 500?

Tags: c#, .net, rest, yammer

While posting messages, Yammer is throwing the following error (and not posting the message):

> The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.

I'm using Yammer .NET wrapper and it's working fine with REST call "https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages.json", but posting message gives the above error.

Below is the code giving us the error message,

```
String consumerkey = "consumerkey";
String clientsecret = "clientsecret";
WebProxy webpro = new WebProxy("ourproxyserver",8080)
webpro.BypassProxyOnLocal = true;
webpro.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
String access_token = "https://www.yammer.com/oauth2/access_token.json"+
                       "?client_id=clientid&"+
                       "client_secret=cli_secret&code=code_id";

Yammer.Session session = new Yammer.Session(
                           new OAuth.OAuthKey(
                                 consumerkey, clientsecret, access_token,"token"
                           ),
                         webpro);

NameValueCollection parameters = new NameValueCollection();
parameters.Add("body", body);

response = Yammer.HttpUtility.Post(Resources.YAMMER_MESSAGES_CREATE, parameters, session);
```

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: No code/traces = unsolvable

Comment: Can you show the code you're using to post the message so we can figure out where the error is?

Comment: Please check the call above, using Yammer .NET wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following wrapper method to post message on yammer (Please note that this code uses `Auth` and `Authbase` class:

```
public static string PostMessage(string body)
{
       NameValueCollection parameters = new NameValueCollection();
       parameters.Add("body", body);
       string response = string.Empty;
       response = Post("https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages/", parameters);
       return response;
}

public static string Post(string url, NameValueCollection parameters)
{
            string nonce, timestamp;
            string fullUrl = EncodeUrl(url, parameters);
            string signature = GetSignature(WebMethod.POST, fullUrl, out timestamp, out nonce);
            HttpWebRequest request = CreateWebRequest(url, WebMethod.POST, nonce, timestamp, signature);
int count = 0;
            string queryString = string.Empty;
            foreach (string key in parameters.Keys)
            {
                if (count == 0)
                    queryString = key + "=" + Rfc3986.Encode(parameters[key]);
                else
                    queryString += "&" + key + "=" + Rfc3986.Encode(parameters[key]);
                count++;
            }


            byte[] postDataBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(queryString);
            request.ContentLength = postDataBytes.Length;
            Stream reqStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            reqStream.Write(postDataBytes, 0, postDataBytes.Length);
            reqStream.Close();

            WebResponse response = null;
            string data = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                response = request.GetResponse();
                data = response.Headers["Location"];
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Error retrieving web response " + ex.Message);
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (response != null)
                    response.Close();
            }
            return data;
        }

        private static string EncodeUrl(string url, NameValueCollection parameters)
        {
            string fullUrl = string.Empty;
            int count = 0;
            foreach (string key in parameters.Keys)
            {
                if (count == 0)
                    fullUrl = url + "?" + key + "=" + Rfc3986.Encode(parameters[key].ToLower());
                else
                    fullUrl += "&" + key + "=" + Rfc3986.Encode(parameters[key].ToLower());
                count++;
            }
            return fullUrl;
        }


public static string GetSignature(WebMethod method, string url, out string timestamp, out string nonce)
        {
            OAuthBase oAuth = new OAuthBase();
            nonce = oAuth.GenerateNonce();
            timestamp = oAuth.GenerateTimeStamp();
            string nurl, nrp;

            Uri uri = new Uri(url);
            string sig = oAuth.GenerateSignature(
                uri,
                YOURCONSUMERKEY,
                YOURCONSUMER_SECRET,
                AuthToken,
                AuthTokenSecret,
                method.ToString(),
                timestamp,
                nonce,
                OAuthBase.SignatureTypes.PLAINTEXT, out nurl, out nrp);

            return System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(sig);
        }

private static HttpWebRequest CreateWebRequest(string fullUrl, WebMethod method, string nonce, string timeStamp, string sig)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(fullUrl);
            request.Method = method.ToString();
            request.Proxy = Yammer.Session.WebProxy;
            string authHeader = CreateAuthHeader(method, nonce, timeStamp, sig);
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", authHeader);
            return request;
        }

private static string CreateAuthHeader(WebMethod method, string nonce, string timeStamp, string sig)
{
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append("OAuth ");
            if (method == WebMethod.POST)
                sb.Append("realm=\"" + "\",");
            else
                sb.Append("realm=\"\",");

            string authHeader = "oauth_consumer_key=\"" + YOURCONSUMERKEY + "\"," +
                                "oauth_token=\"" + YOURAUTHTOKEN  + "\"," +
                                "oauth_nonce=\"" + nonce + "\"," +
                                "oauth_timestamp=\"" + timeStamp + "\"," +
                                "oauth_signature_method=\"" + "HMAC-SHA1" + "\"," +
                                "oauth_version=\"" + "1.0" + "\"," +
                                "oauth_signature=\"" + sig + "\"";

            sb.Append(authHeader);
            return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: You should try to avoid using OAuth 1.0 code like this and choose to use OAuth 2.0. It will simplify your code, and OAuth 2.0 is the best supported option for Yammer.